# Is there a way to group the inner array object using angular ag-grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

**Is there a way to group the array of objects inside the table as per the screenshot given below**

- tried using angular ag grid grouping-custom-group-columns yet it is working only on the string array not the object array.

[image: Screenshot]

**Data : **

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "unit":"01111", 
    "coid":"03111", 
    "facilityName":"abc company", 
    "market":"Charleston", 
    "mcMarket":"Carolina", 
    "production":"02/01/23", 
    "inactive":"5/01/23",
    "cdm": [{
      "id": 1,
      "cdmDate":"10/01/23", 
      "cdmPct":"8.00", 
      "exclusions":"250, 252"
    }] 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for aggrid row spanning

[Row Spanning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-spanning/)

> Javascript
> By default, each cell will take up the height of one row. You can change this behaviour to allow cells to span multiple rows. This feature is similar to 'cell merging' in Excel or 'row spanning' in HTML tables.